# Does eWay payment processor work for Membership auto-renew

Tags: civimember, eway, auto-renew

Our testing on 4.7.9 is showing that eWay is not letting the auto-renew options show on the Membership settings tab on a Contribution page configuration.

The [wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Payment+Processors) says eWay's 'recurring contributions / auto-renew memberships' is currently "Code written but needs further customisation, see work in progress" which links [here](https://github.com/henare/CiviCRM-eWay-recurring-payment-processor) which then sends you on to [here](https://github.com/ChrisChinchilla/CiviCRM-eWay-recurring-payment-processor) and also directs you straight to the [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/eway-recurring-payment-processor)

Having enabled this extension (v 1.1) on the site, the auto-renew options remain unavailable on the contribution settings page.

Currently we have one page that offers PayPal and PayLater and the auto-renew options are available in the config, and show on the page. But an equivalent page that has PayPal+PayLater+eWay does not give us the options we need.

Comment: Well i needed to go in and create a new Payment Processor using the 'eway recurring' option which now exists. progress. then needed to set up API Key with eway. Done. now waiting on 2nd payment to go through tomorrow to confirm recurring Contributions is working. then need to test/repeat with Auto Renew.

Comment: Hi Pete, did you find that the auto-renewing membership with eway worked?

Comment: From memory we had to do some work that is promising but needed some extra testing effort but also there was another thread of work to ensure eWay and recurring works on the newer RapidAPI approach

Comment: Pete - I've just seen this in the list of related questions - probably way out of date now! But in case it's helpful, we are using eWay happily with recurring payments and auto-renew for memberships.